# MySQL can I insert specific ids into an auto-increment column

Tags: mysql

I accidentally deleted some rows in my database, but I have a copy of the data in a backup.

Is it possible to insert the rows back in with the same id (auto-increment field). Or do I have to use the auto-increment generated id then update all the relationships manually?

Comment: What kind of backup file is it? Yes it is possible to reinsert depending on how you backed up your data.

Comment: Its a mysqldump. I have it loaded into another instance of the database. Do you have a link to syntax for this, as I am sure I got an error the last time I tried an "insert into ... select * from ..."?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can, just by setting the field when INSERTing. [Autoincrement only works if no value is specified for the field](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html).